# CLLocationManagerDelegate most accurate position

Tags: objective-c, ios6, mkmapview, cllocationmanager

I have a simple App here that gets the user most accurate position and display it on a MKMapView. I'm using the code below.

```
- (void) locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateLocations:(NSArray *)locations
{
    CLLocation *location = [locations lastObject];
    NSDate *eventDate = location.timestamp;
    NSTimeInterval howRecent = [eventDate timeIntervalSinceNow];
    if (abs(howRecent) < 15.0){
        [manager stopUpdatingLocation];
        previusViewController.coordinate = location.coordinate;
        [self exhibitMap:location.coordinate];
    }
}
```

The problem is that this delegate method is called many times by default, and that makes my MKMapView to pin multiple annotations sometimes. Please let me know if anyone faced this issue before, and if there is a straightforward solution for that.

thanks,
marcos.

Answer (score 0):

I solved my problem using the command bellow before add the MKPointAnnotation:

```
[self.map removeAnnotations:self.map.annotations];
```